# Disadvantages of coding in C#6.0 but compiling against .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, c#-6.0

This question popped into my head today.

C#6.0 or any other version for that matter all introduce cool new functionality making things easier to code.

But lets say I have a client running WindowsXP which doesnt support .NET 4.6.

Are they any downsides to writing my code in C#6.0 (or whatever the latest C# version is in the future) but compiling it against the .NET 2.0 framework (or some other version of .NET which is different than the C# version that it was released with)

**EDIT**

For those who are unaware you can target the .NET Framework via Project Properties -> Application tab -> Target Framework

and you can target the C# Language Version via Project Properties -> Build tab -> Advanced -> Language Version.

**EDIT2 - C#6.0 Code Compiled on .NET 2.0 and run on WindowsXP**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        string value = sb?.ToString();  // C#6 Feature. Wont throw an exception. 

        if(value == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Value is null");
        }

        string value2 = sb.ToString();  // Will cause an "Object Reference not set to an instance" exception

    }
    catch ( Exception ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("object")) // C#6.0 conditional catches
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Caught");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Other Exception");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: @Vladimir Not true.  Many C# 6.0 features are compile time while the version of .Net is run time.  It only effects what libraries you can use.

Comment: @Vladimir Thats not true. Ive added some C#6.0 code to my question which compiles and runs on .net 2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are they any downsides to writing my code in C#6.0 (or whatever the latest C# version is in the future) but compiling it against the .NET 2.0 framework (or some other version of .NET which is different than the C# version that it was released with)

Only that there will be features you can't use:

- LINQ unless you provide your own implementation
- Expression trees
- Extension methods unless you add your own attribute
- `FormattableString` for interpolated strings (minor; you can still use interpolated strings as strings)
- Dynamic typing
- Generic variance
- Caller info unless you add your own attributes
- Async/await (not sure how feasible it would be to provide your own implementation of this... pretty major job)

Other features such as lambda expressions, expression-bodied members, anonymous types etc should work fine.

Comment: I'm curious, how can I write extension methods using .net2.0 by creating an attribute? Could you provide a link?

Comment: @RenéVogt: Basically if you create your own `ExtensionAttribute` in the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace, the compiler will use it.

Comment: Still, Windows XP supports .net 4, which will give you access to some of the features above

Comment: @EliPerl Windows XP was just an example. The question is really about compiling the code against a different version of the .net framework.

Comment: thanks Jon, did not know that it's such a simple compiler magic that kept us from using extensions in our legacy project (needs to stay on 2.0). Now I'm just not sure if it's legal to copy the source code of the linq extensions or if we have to reimplement them :)

Comment: @RenéVogt: For LINQ, you might want to look at LinqBridge:http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx If at all possible, of course, I'd try really hard to update... .NET 2.0 hasn't been supported for a long time.